# Javascript Alert onClick Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, submit, alert

I am using code found on the link below to add a checkbox to my form that fires an alert box if the user submits the form without the checkbox being checked, but for some reason its not working.

http://www.webfoot-designs.com/blog/2012/05/09/create-a-check-box-statement-before-continuing/

And here is the link to the web page that I'm using it on...

http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/hotels/spanish-modern-retreat/

First, click "Availability" from the left side menu and then click "BooK Now" to be able to see the form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should show code in your question and a jsfiddle would be useful too!

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CzHBlkn9Pz

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the javascript code you provided here: jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CzHBlkn9Pz

The line `form.submit-accommodation-booking.disabled = true;` throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. I've never seen a submit button queried like that so I don't know if it's syntactically incorrect or it's just plain invalid javascript. However, replacing that line with the following will achieve the same intention.

In a pure javascript manner, what you want is

```
document.getElementById("submit-accommodation-booking").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
```

Remember, all modern browsers ship with extremely useful debug tools that'll help you catch these problems. For chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools Firefox and safari have very similar options.